# Let D be a UFD. Show that a nonconstant divisor of a primitive polynomial in D[x] is again a primitive polynomial.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

Laying out the clues, I have $f(x), g(x) \in D[x]$. Assume that $g(x)|f(x) = c(x)$ such that $f(x) = c(x)g(x)$.

Given that g(x) is a primitive polynomial, does this mean any factorization such that $f(x) = c(x)g(x)$ implies that c(x) is a unit in D and c(x)? is the "content"?

Expanding the notation of f(x), we have $f(x) = (c_1(x)c_2(x)...c_i(x))(g_1(x)g_2(x)...g_i(x))$.. then I'm not sure how to proceed from here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: $c\mid f\mid g\,\Rightarrow\,c\mid g\ \ $

Answer (score 2):

Saying that the factor is not primitive means that a prime/irreducible divides it: so $f(x)=pf_1(x)$ for some prime $p\in D$.

Thus $g(x)=pf_1(x)c(x)$ is not primitive.

Comment: So.. a proof by contradiction?

Comment: @SquiresMcGee Contrapositive.